# what is locks in db.currentOp() of mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to insert millions of records into the database. During insertion I saw the below lock json. Can someone explain what is "^"? is it global write lock? I thought global write lock is removed in latest DB. FYI `emails_5` is the database I am inserting records into.

```
"locks" : {
                "^" : "w",
                "^local" : "W",
                "^emails_5" : "W"
            },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These locks are denoting the type of locks as can be seen here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/current-op/#currentOp.locks

The capital `W` or `R` denotes global write lock while the lower case `w` and `r` denotes database specific locks.

Basically that output there states that for `mongod` (`^`) you are using the database specific lock on `local` database and `emails_5` database.